# Run command using rsh on a remote computer

Tags: python, subprocess, rsh

I am trying to run a python script, and I need to  Rsh a command from the script, the command I want to run is : `df -Pk|grep "sd\|md"|gawk '{print $2}'`

and I do it as -

```
cmd2='df -Pk|grep \\\"sd\|md\\\"|gawk \'{print $2}\''
process = subprocess.Popen(['rsh',ip,cmd2],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

However when I do run the script,I get nothing in output.

I am new to python and as far as I know, its a problem with the escape characters.

Any help would be great.

Note:
I have to use Rsh only and cannot use ssh

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you miss a backslash to escape the one after sd

Comment: Have you tried using a much simpler command, like ls, to verify the communication?  Have you tried executing the df/grep command locally?

Comment: @Sid Sorry about that, it was a typo.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, I have run the command locally and checked the communication as well. It works. The following works as well -
cmd = 'df -Pk'
process = subprocess.Popen(['rsh',ip,cmd],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the command, with proper shell quoting, in triple quote marks:

```
"""df -Pk|grep "sd\|md"|gawk '{print $2}'"""
```

See also the Python tutorial's [bit on strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: @jdi: you removed the `\` before `|`, which changes the `grep` RE's meaning.

Comment: withdrawn lol. I was only thinking about the string formatting on its own and forgot to consider the subprocess :-)

Comment: @larsmans Thanks for the link. However the triple quotes didn't help.

Comment: @sudologin: What do you mean by "it didn't help"? Did you try running the command through `sh` instead of `rsh`?

Comment: @larsmans Yes I did that. However I got to work now, used just  
'df -Pk' as 'cmd' and did rest of the parsing on the host(local), works perfect.